# npm install doesn't install dependencies in Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have an Angular project. When I run *npm install* I see some errors and dependencies don't appear in *node_modules* folder. However, I think none of the errors explain the problem. I see some deprecation warnings and 404 for one dependency, but nothing more.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.0",
    "@css-pkg/circular-std": "^2.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.12.1",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars": "^18.1.44",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.38",
    "alertifyjs": "^1.13.1",
    "angular-mat-datepicker": "0.0.2",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.21",
    "angularx-qrcode": "^2.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "material-steppers": "^2.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.900.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

And here is the log output:

```
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@css-pkg%2fcircular-std - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@css-pkg/circular-std@^2.0.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'traveler-frontend'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mac/.npm/_logs/2020-06-16T20_33_51_531Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `"@css-pkg/circular-std": "^2.0.0",` line. Because it's not found in the npm package registry. Try `npm install` again.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. It seems that npm doesn't ho further when it encounters a dependency it cannot resolve

Answer (score 0):

The error says `@css-pkg/circular-std` can't be found. That package may be removed from npm directory. While searching the package I couldn't find it in the directory.